# Appending multiple times to same File using "a" mode

Tags: c

I'm trying to update an invoice file, i wrote 2 functions, first one is called multiple times to fill in the names and prices. second one is called once to write the final taxes/discounts..etc
Problem is, the second function outputs text before the first function.
i'm sure the functions are called in the correct order.
code:

```
 int Update_Invoice(int No, int feeType) //update invoice file
{
    char type[2][8] = { {"Normal"},{"Urgent"} };
    int Fee = fees[No][feeType - 1]; //temporary variable to store fee of specific service type

    FILE* fptr = fopen(InvoiceName, "a");
    if (fptr == NULL)
        exit(1);
    else
    {   
        fprintf(fptr, "%-30s\t\t%s\t\t%d\n", serviceType[No],type[feeType-1], fees[No][feeType-1]);
        return Fee;
    }
    fclose(fptr);
}
void Calculate_Final_Price(double total, double discount, double tax)
{
    FILE* fptr = fopen(InvoiceName, "a");
    if (fptr == NULL)
        exit(1);
    else
    {
        fprintf(fptr, "-----------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        fprintf(fptr,"\t\t\t\t\tSubTotal\t%.2lf\n",total);
        fprintf(fptr, "\t\t\t\t\tDiscount\t%.2lf\n", discount);
        fprintf(fptr, "\t\t\t\t\tTax\t\t%.2lf\n", tax);
        total -= ((total * discount) / 100); // apply discount
        total += tax; // apply taxes
        fprintf(fptr, "\t\t\t\t\tTotal\t\t%.2lf\n",total); //final price
    }
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

actuall txt file:

```
Invoice Number: 200052


Service                 Type        Price
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
-->this should be in the end        SubTotal    876.00
-->this should be in the end        Discount    0.00    
-->this should be in the end        Tax         0.00
-->this should be in the end        Total       876.00

Full Car Checkup                    Normal      300
Repair punctured car tyre/piece     Urgent      6
Battery change                      Urgent      210
Synthetic oil change                Normal      130
Mineral oil change                  Normal      80
Car tyre change/piece               Normal      150
```

Comment: _"i'm sure the functions are called in the correct order."_  You should prepare a [mcve]

Comment: Can you show the function that does that calling?  It kind of sounds like that is where the problem is.  Also, it seems like `InvoiceName` is either static to the c file or a global.  Wouldn't it be easier to make the `FILE*` global (or passed a parameter).  That way you don't need to open and close it constantly.

Comment: You might want to use a debugger to step through the code statement by statement to make sure it behaves as you expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the problem is probably here:

```
else
{   
        fprintf(fptr, "%-30s\t\t%s\t\t%d\n", serviceType[No],type[feeType-1], fees[No][feeType-1]);
        return Fee;
}
fclose(fptr);
```

that code *returns* without closing the file. So the line isn't flushed at once and it conflicts with the other file object. Fix:

```
else
{   
    fprintf(fptr, "%-30s\t\t%s\t\t%d\n", serviceType[No],type[feeType-1], fees[No][feeType-1]);
    fclose(fptr);
    return Fee;
}
```

(as a bonus you're no longer invoking undefined behaviour by trying to close a `NULL` file object)